# Recitation of the Iliad

Tags: pronunciation, ancient-greek, resource-request, homeric-greek

I'm a beginner in Ancient Greek trying to learn about pronouciation. I'm particularly interested in  Homer's Iliad.

I'm aware that this is a controversial topic, to put it mildly, so I don't expect definitive answers.

My question is: where can I find a "good" recorded recitation of the Iliad?

By "good" I mean "interesting in any way you consider important" (even if the justification is simply "this one sounds beautiful, although probably incorrect").

If the answers contradict one another, I'll be happy to know about the controversies.

Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

Stephen Daitz's recitation of the *Iliad* was at least before and probably still is the most regarded. However, I believe it's not freely available online. Instead, you'll have to track it down from a library [or purchase it](https://www.bolchazy.com/Search.aspx?k=Stephen+Daitz). These used to come on cassettes, but the Bolchazy downloads are very affordable. I'm not entirely sure of the process, but I think the original cassettes were turned into WAV files and then into MP3s, which is what you can download.

Two others I found:

- [David Chamberlain's](https://hypotactic.com/my-reading-of-homer-work-in-progress/), which has all of the *Iliad* and some of the *Odyssey*:
- [Julius Tomin's](http://www.juliustomin.org/), with a bunch of other works. Tomin is a philosopher, not a Classicist, and I can't vouch for their quality, but maybe someone else can chime in.